# JSON data is showing as array

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to test an API in ADF. My source for the copy activity is JSON, but when I retrieve the sample JSON file, it looks like the data is in an array.

[image: Sample]

How can I remove the square brackets? This is causing my pipeline to fail.
Thanks!

Comment: const response = getJSON();
const data = response[0];

Comment: Hi @AnkanBag - I'm not sure if this is possible in ADF.

Comment: Oops! I didn't noticed that. You may try changing the *array of documents* in the *source options* tab.

Comment: Hi @AnkanBag - Sadly, I am not seeing any array of documents in the Source settings.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your console? Here's the link for the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json) which might be helpful to you.

Comment: please post the settings of your copy activity with sample file

Answer (score 0):

[Collection reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#hierarchical-source-to-tabular-sink) is applied to flatten the nested array in JSON data using Copy Activity.

[image]

[image]